# Python Code not printing function outputs in jupyter

Tags: python, function, output, jupyter

I have defined my functions however when I try and make them print they print as `< function salinity_seawater at 0x2537f670 >`

I have tried restarting multiple times but nothing works.

Here is the section of code:

```
def sal_of_seawater(l): 
        sal_of_seawater = (-0.0222*l)+34
        return sal_of_seawater

    print("A latitude of", l, "equals a salinity value of", sal_of_seawater)
```

the output of the code:

```
A latitude of 45 equals a salinity of <function sal_of_seawater at 0x109f29730>
```

Comment: no i havent, how would this improve the situation? i am new to coding

Comment: pass an argument to sal_of_seawater function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your print statement is wrong.to get return statement of function,call it like

```
print("A latitude of", l, "equals a salinity value of", sal_of_seawater(10))
```

Or

```
print("A latitude of", l, "equals a salinity value of", sal_of_seawater(l))
```

Define l accordingly

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it

```
def sal_of_seawater(l): 
        res = (-0.0222*l)+34
        return res

l = 45

print("A latitude of", l, "equals a salinity value of", sal_of_seawater(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
l =45
print("A latitude of {} equals a salinity value of {}".format(l, sal_of_seawater(l)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code below returns an output:

`A latitude of 45 equals a salinity value of 33.001`

Instead of returning the calculated value, I directly put the `print` inside the `def sal_of_seawater(l):`

Then calling `sal_of_seawater(<some value>)` to return an output.

```
def sal_of_seawater(l): 
    sal_of_seawater = (-0.0222*l)+34
    print("A latitude of", l, "equals a salinity value of", sal_of_seawater)

sal_of_seawater(45)
```

Answer (score 0):

First assuming you are new to Stackoverflow check out different formatting options available in Stackoverflow so that the other person can clearly understand what your code does. For example I guess your code should be like this:
(For code formatting Ctrl+K)

```
def sal_of_seawater(l): 
        sal_of_seawater = (-0.0222*l)+34
        return sal_of_seawater
l = 45
print("A latitude of", l, "equals a salinity value of", sal_of_seawater)
```

Here the print function is working properly the issue lies in the argument being not passed in the function calling namely sal_of_seawater in the print function passing sal_of_seawater(l) will solve the issue.

Functions in Python are themselves an object, and an object has some value
Since you have not passed any argument, the function doesn't run over here and hence returns a default value 0x109f29730 which is the location of the object.

PS: You may go through this link to understand more about functions in Python : https://www.guru99.com/functions-in-python.html

Comment: You were returning the  saltwater function itself. You needed to put the argument and  evaluate the function in the print statement. That's why you had it wrong